# PHP CURL multipart form data not uploading file (PHP Ver. 5.6)

Tags: php, curl, telegram-bot

I have a method to send requests to Telegram, this function act normally as expected on my server. After transfer to costumer server I get error from Telegram: `Bad Request: URL host is empty`.

The data that is send through Curl is:

```
$data = array(
    "chat_id" => "user_id",
    "video"   => "@/path/to/file/tested/successfully",
    "caption" => "My Text"
);
```

And options that set for curl is as below:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'URL/TO/TELEGRAM/API');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: multipart/form-data"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

This code work properly on my server and I think there is a configuration that has to be set on server.

Another issue that should be related is: when I provide wrong path to the file, on first server I get expected `Error Code: 3, Couldn't open file` from curl but on second server I'll get `Bad Request: URL host is empty` again.

So maybe I can say that curl on second server can not understand that the `video` index is a file.

**First server is dedicated, but second one is shared host (2 host tested)** *(Discovery 1)*
**First server php version was 5.5.38, but second one was 5.6** *(Discovery 2)*
**After changing second php version to 5.5.38, it works correctly** *(Discovery 3)*

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in php ver 5.5 and above set `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, true)` and change the `@/pathToFile` to `new \CURLFile($pathToFile)`. 
according to php [changeLog](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.changed-functions.php) :

> Uploads using the @file syntax are now only supported if the CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD option is set to FALSE. CURLFile should be used instead.

turning CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD to false is not best practice and deprecated
read the first comment [here](http://php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php) for more info about CURLFile.

Comment: Short, accurate & complete answer. Thank you so much